# How to print the first rows of a flextable?

Tags: r, flextable

Is there a way to print the first rows of a flextable? I would like to reduce the size of my flextable in a rmarkdown document, as in DT :: datatable.
Thanks.

```
library(florestal)
data(simple2)
acs1 <- acs(simple2, A=27, a=0.1)

acs1$`vol individual`
```

Comment: Could you pass just the first few rows of the data frame to the flextable function eg instead of passing `df` to flextable pass `head(df, n)` where `n` is the number of rows you want to include.

Comment: I can't do this because the function returns a flextable from a list...

Comment: Perhaps you could include a reproducible example [https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example] to make the question clearer and provide a starting point to test and verify a solution?

Comment: I wrote the example in the question now. Thank you!

Comment: you can get the data from a flextable using `acs1$body$dataset` and then head that?